# Last Step of installation on RPi Failing

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the Raspberry Pi Indigo installation guide here:  http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

CMake is failing on the last step with this error: [http://i.imgur.com/P9l5Gnr.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/P9l5Gnr.jpg)

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'ecl_time'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ecl_core/ecl_time -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ecl_time -DCMA
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ecl_time
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ecl_time/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_build/cmake/ecl_cx11.cmake:17 (message):
  Requested cxx11 flags, but this compiler does not support it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (ecl_enable_cxx11_compiler)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'ecl_time': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ecl_core/ecl_time', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ecl_time && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ecl_core/ecl_timelease -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

I'm not sure how to correct this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217536/last-step-of-installation-on-rpi-failing/) by [gsav55](https://answers.ros.org/users/23847/gsav55/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-11**:
Please copy/paste console output into your question text: if your image ever gets deleted / the host dies, this question (and future answer) will be useless.

Be sure to format console text using the *preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [gsav55](https://answers.ros.org/users/23847/gsav55/) on 2015-09-11**:
I edited it.  It seems to be coming from

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_build/cmake/ecl_cx11.cmake:17 (message):
  Requested cxx11 flags, but this compiler does not support it.
```

but I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the same problem. Deleting the ecl_time package doesn't help because other packages depends on it.
Last June I  compiled it without problems.
Any help please

Mauro

---

Originally posted by [Mauro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2219/mauro/) with karma: 16 on 2015-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mauro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2219/mauro/) on 2015-09-30**:
The problem seems resolved.
I substituted the ecl_time and ecl_devices folders with the ones in release 0.61.0 Sept 2014 and it compiles.

Mauro